# Searching large structured numpy arrays quickly

Tags: python, arrays, search, numpy, set

I have a structured numpy array of format

```
dataZero = [(1000, 1045),  # ('gid','lpid')
            (2345, 2500),
                 ...    ]
```

which has ~130,000 entries in it. I also have another structured array of format

```
dataSnap = [(1002,...,...,...),   # ('gid',...)
            (2400,...,...,...),
            (2490,...,...,...),
                 ...          ]
```

but this contains 2 million entries.

For every entry in `dataZero`, `i`, I want to find the entries in `dataSnap` that satisfy the condition `dataZero['gid'][i] <= dataSnap['gid'] <= dataZero['lpid'][i]`. This should allow for multiple entries to be returned. It can either return the indices of the entries that meet this condition, or the entries themselves - as long as I do this within a reasonable amount of time ~minutes.

In the above example, this would return, for example:

```
[some code] -> [[0],[1,2],...]   # if returning indices of dataSnap

[some code] -> [[(1002,...,...,...)],  # if returning the entries themselves
                [(2400,...,...,...),(2490,...,...,...)],
               ...]
```

I can't figure out how to do this quickly - a for loop takes ages. Might some conversion to a set `{}` be better? Any advice/solutions are appreciated.

Comment: Are both arrays sorted?  Are the ranges in `dataZero` non-overlapping?

Comment: The arrays are not sorted. The ranges in dataZero do not overlap.

Comment: Can they become sorted?  Once they are sorted the task becomes trivial.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski - They can be. The current order is not important.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an algorithm using Python sorted lists (not arrays).  You may need to adjust it to work with `numpy`.

```
def helper(dataZero, dataSnap): # assumes arguments are sorted ascending!
    ds_iter = iter(dataSnap)
    curr_snap = next(ds_iter)
    for lo, hi in dataZero:
        while curr_snap[0] < lo:
            curr_snap = next(ds_iter)
        while lo <= curr_snap[0] <= hi:
            yield curr_snap
            curr_snap = next(ds_iter) 

result = list(helper(dataZero, dataSnap))
```

I tested this with `dataSnap` containing 2 million randomly generated entries and `dataZero` containing 130k randomly chosen ranges from `dataSnap`.  It took at most couple of seconds on my system.

Comment: This does what you say, however if a dataZero entry has multiple solutions, this doesn't group them together in the resulting list. Can this be done?

Comment: I can just `yield (curr_snap,lo)` and work with this.